# DataGridView.DataSource not working when defining columns from code

Tags: c#, .net

I want to define the columns of my DataGridView manually from code. Something like this:

```
int index = 0;
string columnName = "something";

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

column.Name = columnName;
column.HeaderText = columnName;

myDataGridView.Columns.Insert(index++, column);
```

And then I bind the DataGridView.DataSource to a DataTable:

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = null;
table = new DataTable();
table = dbAccess.GetDataFromDB(); //This function returns a DataTable filled with data
myDataGridView.DataSource = table;
```

I already checked that after executing GetDataFromDB table is filled with data, but when binding it to DataSource, the DataGridView keeps all its row empty (although it creates as many rows as there are on the table).

Some code that I'm missing here?

Comment: You need to set "DataPropertyName" property of `column` to the name of the columnname from the datatable...

Comment: Already tried that, didn't work

Comment: GridView Columns are not showing data because it's not specified from which datatable column the should be showed.... One more thing you can try is instead of adding columns at run time, let the GridView generate the column automatically based on the datatable structure....

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: That's what I did before, but now I've been commanded to define columns manually. It's some kind of class exercise, so defining columns at run time it's mandatory

Comment: It worked with DataPropertyName. Thanks a lot